# How to write multiple "_or_ (i.e. ||)" conditions in Makefile.am?

Tags: makefile, autotools

I am looking for the way to write multipule "OR" condition in Makefile.am. 
For example, what if only MOBILE is defined and Makefile.am is written as below.

```
if (MOBILE || PC_CLIENT)
    # stuff
endif
```

Unfortunately this Makefile.am code returns compile time error.

What is the right way to do as same?

Comment: Here's the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html

Answer (score 2):

You can not find big flexibility in `Makefile.am`. However the usual practice is to perform the complex tasks in `configure.ac` and then pass a simple parameter to `Makefile.am. The`configure.ac`uses`bash`commands and in this case you can use`test`of`bash`:

`configure.ac`

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([STUFF], [test $var1 = "MOBILE" -o  $var1 = "PC_CLIENT"])
```

`Makefile.am`

```
if STUFF
   # stuff
endif
```

Check the documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Usage-of-Conditionals.html#Usage-of-Conditionals).